# Redirect url according to selection option

Tags: jquery, html

i faced a problem while making my website , its supposed to redirect me to another index when i choose a specific option
for exemple when i select "Membre bénevole" the page "reg-benevole.html" will be loaded .
and when i select "Responsable association", the page "reg-assocation.html" will be loaded.

### but when i tested it just loads reg-benevole.html everytime for both options ...

```
    `<div class="form-group">
        <select id="cat" style="width:80%;" class="form-control" name="option">
            <option value="Responsable association" onChange="catgValue =this.value;"> Responsable
                association </option>
            <option value="Membre bénevole" onChange="catgValue =this.value;">Membre bénevole
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="s" class="btn btn-primary" value="Soumettre">
    </div>`
```

and the Jquery Code :

```
   $(document).on('click', '#s', function () {
if (catgValue = 'Membre bénevole') {
    window.location.href = "reg-benevole.html";
}
else if (catgValue = 'Responsable association') {
    window.location.href = "reg-assocation.html";
}
```

});

Comment: You are setting the catgValue to the 'Membre bénevole'. Use == to compare

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**1st:**</sup> You are using a single '=' to compare. You need to use '==' (or '==='), like:

<sup>**2nd:**</sup> You need to get the select value inside the submit input click not outside it

<sup>**3rd:**</sup> You may need `e.preventDefault()` if you use the input inside form OR change the input type to `button`

<sup>**4th:**</sup> For double check you can use `.trim()` to avoid white spaces

```
$(document).on('click', '#s', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var catgValue = $('#cat').val().trim(); 
  if (catgValue == 'Membre bénevole') {
    window.location.href = "reg-benevole.html";
  }
  else if (catgValue == 'Responsable association') {
    window.location.href = "reg-assocation.html";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only are you setting with a single = sign, but it is best to do `change` not the `click` event for selects. You don't need the onchange event in the options.

```
$(document).on('change', '#s option', function () {
if (this.value == 'Membre bénevole') {
    window.location.href = "reg-benevole.html";
}
else if (this.value == 'Responsable association') {
    window.location.href = "reg-assocation.html";
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers ! i appreciate this too much i changed the code like this and nothing yet .. (btw thanks for reminding me about the "==" i was kinda drunk xDD 
and i used "click" cuz it belongs to the submit button not the select options

```
    $(document).on('click', '#s', function () {
if (catgValue == 'Membre bénevole') {
    window.location.href = "reg-benevole.html";
}
else if (catgValue == 'Responsable association') {
    window.location.href = "reg-assocation.html";
}
```

})

Comment: No need to post that as an answer .. you can just check the accepted answer from the posted answers

Comment: Welcome aboard @malekabbes - you should delete this "answer" because people will eventually downvote it which will hurt your reputation points.